# I need a good and intelligent IDE to use for Web development

Tags: javascript, html, web-development, css

I am new to web development and i have been trying to understand using Intellij IDEA and Vs Code but I don't quite get how to set the files and some of their features properly, please i need someone to suggest or recommend an IDE to use and a resource to learn about it from, thanks in advance.

Comment: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/what-to-do-with-these-cross-platform-development-environment-questions-are-th

Comment: @JanDoggen I saw those other questions and they didn't answer my question, my question neither broad because i mentioned, i need a IDE for web development not cross platform, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) which one of the smartest JavaScript IDE

Comment: JetBrains make the best IDEs for any language. I am currently using WebStorm, PhpStorm, PyCharm and CLion, plus their free YouTrack to Kanban my projects. Yay, JetBrains !